# Maven reduce bundles size by excluding unneeded dependencies in bulk?

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, pom.xml

The project I'm working on has dependencies on a few well known and big libraries. Things are working well, the transitive dependencies are playing nice with each other, for now. But unfortunately the total bundle size is around 100 megs.

I'm not sure if this is too large or not, but is there a way in maven to effectively remove dependencies, without making pom.xml very verbose and long?

And pointers to help me in the right direction would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove dependencies by declaring exclusions. The question I would post to first though is .. why do you want to remove them?

Unless you know that the dependencies are not needed, it might not make sense to try to remove them. Especially not if there are no issues e.g. in terms of application performance or startup times.

The Maven Dependency Plugin as well as the Eclipse integration have tools that allow you to understand the dependencies better with tools like the dependency:tree goal or the Dependnecy Hierarchy view of the POM.

Don't try to fix something that is not broken.

BUT ..

if you really know what is needed at runtime and use the tooling from Maven and M2e you can potentially remove a lot of bulk of your final artifact. However you will have to configure it in the pom using dependency exclusions. Newer Maven versions even allow patterns being used.

Another thing you can do is use a tool like proguard that removes all unused classes from the final artifact. This can be considerably complex but also VERY effective.

It will really be up to you to find the right balance between effort and benefit of outcome.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I agree its not a big problem, but I guess it just feels strange deploying a 100MB plus jar for what is a relatively lightweight batch application. And to be honest, my colleagues aren't exactly happy with the tons of libraries being included, since it makes dependency clashes that much more possible in the future, in a way making the app more 'fragile'.


Also yes, only a tiny fraction of the library is being used, because it was meant to run on its own cluster. We're only using it for some of its api's that makes ETL jobs a lot easier/cleaner

Comment: @JeffLL I added some more helping details and steps if you want to go down that road.